# How to test whether a given functional code unit (C#) does NOT create/write any files to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

Imagine there's a mission-critical process that'll be used in a business which handles sensitive information (think of Credit Card, social security, patient records...etc). I would think this unit ideally should do whatever it has to do on-the-fly, meaning it won't intentionally write files to disk containing sensitive information. The idea here is that if the computer that runs this process is compromised, no sensitive information can be leaked, at least not by means of files.

What approaches could be taken to, say, come up with a unit test that will **fail** if the unit under test tries to write **any** file to disk?

Comment: If I was you I'd run process monitor via http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carloc/archive/2008/10/31/how-to-automate-process-monitor.aspx and parse the output for file writes from your unit test runner application (nunit or whatever). Just an idea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the FileSystemWatcher (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/filesystemwatcher-in-C-Sharp/) however this requires you to know a specific directory.  In your case this probably isn't very helpful since the program could write anything to disk any where.  This introduces a unique problem.  However, I have also found something called Detours from Microsoft.  This appears to intercept all native win32 api calls.  http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/  The issue with this is that its kind of hard to test, and integrating it into unit testing will be a challenge.

When you have to treat your software as "untrusted" in the sense that you need to prove it doesn't do something, testing becomes a complex task that requires you to run them on very controlled environments.  When hooking in to the Win32 API, you will be deluged with API calls that need to be processed quickly.  This can result in unintentional side effects because the application is not running in a truly native environment.

My suggestion to you (having worked several years doing software testing for Pharma automation to the exacting standards of the FDA) is to create a controlled environment, eg a virtual machine, that has a known starting state.  This can be accomplished by never actually saving vmdk changes to disk.  You have to take a snapshot of the file system.  You can do this by writing a C# app to enumerate all files on the virtual drive, getting their size, some timestamps and maybe even a hash of the file.  This can be time consuming so you may want (or be able) to skip the hashing.  Create some sort of report, easiest would be by dropping them in a CSV or XML export.  You then run your software under normal circumstances for a set period of time.  Once this is complete, you run a file system analysis again and compare the results.  There are some good apps out there for comparing file contents (like WinMerge).  When taking these snap shots, the best way to do it would be to mount the vmdk as a drive in the host OS.  This will bypass any file locks the guest OS might have.

This method is time intensive but quite thorough.  If you don't need something of this depth, you can use something like Process Monitor and write the output to a file and run a report against that.  However in my work I would have to prove that Process Monitor shows all IO before I could use it which can be just as hard as the method I spoke of above.

Just my 2 cents.

**UPDATE:**

I've been thinking about it, and you might be able to achieve fairly reliable results if you remove all references to System.IO from your code.  Write a library to wrap around System.IO that either does not implement a write method, or only implements one that also writes to a log file.  In this case, you simply have to validate that every time a write occurs using your library, it gets logged.  Then validate using reflection that you don't reference System.IO outside of this new wrapper library.  Your tests can then simply look at this log file to make sure only approved writes are occurring.  You could make use of a SQL Database instead of a flat log file to help avoid cases of tampering or contaminated results.  This should be much easier to validate than trying to script a virtual machine setup like I described above.  This, of course, all requires you to access to the source code of the "untrusted" application, although since you are unit testing it, I assume you do.

Comment: My primary concern is to ensure that the code doesn't do anything it isn't supposed to do. Automating a VM generation/snapshot/comparison cycle would give me the reassurance that it is so.

Comment: @ArcaArtem I thought of another method of testing, let me know what you think

Comment: As @Fabske suggested, abstracting System.IO (eg. [System.IO.Abstractions](http://systemioabstractions.codeplex.com)), and using FxCop/StyleCop to restrict devs not use System.IO could ensure that our code doesn't write to disk. The feedback received with this method will be received much faster compared to VM approach. However, if the code has dependencies that aren't under our control, this would not work. I think both approaches should be used in this case, i.e. restrict System.IO usage for in house, use VM snapshot comparison to ensure no other dependency writes to disk.

Answer (score 2):

1st option:
Maybe you could use Code Access Security, but the "Deny" is obsolete in .NET 4 (but should works in previous version):

```
[FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.Deny)]
public class MyClass 
{
  ...
}
```

You may reactivate this behavior in .NET 4 using [NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409253%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

2nd option:
reducing the level of privilege may also works, as I know that downloaded app can't write on the disk and must use a special storage area.

3rd option:
Remove any reference to System.IO and replace by an interface that your code must use to write data to disk.
Then write an implementation that use System.IO (in a separate project)
In the nunit test, mock this interface and throw an exception when a method id called.

Problem is to ensure any developers will not call System.IO anymore. You can try to do this by enforcing coding rules using FxCop (or other similar tools)

Comment: I never considered using StyleCop or FxCop for this purpose. Good call.

Comment: Main concern is to ensure that the code doesn't do what it isn't supposed to do. Using CAS or abstracting System.IO would help me to do that on the code that I have control over, but not the external dependencies. Using FXCop or equivalent is a good idea to get an immediate feedback on in-house code.